# Sychronous generator vs dc generator

Tags: generator, short-circuit

I am wondering, if a sychronous generator has a smaller posibility to be burnt (be destroyed permanently) from a short circuit, that has a dc generator with parallel wound or a seperately excited dc generator, and why?

Answer (score 2):

There is such a distinction in generators used in motor cars.

Long ago, DC generators were used. They were prone to overheating and to burning their brushes. They needed current limiting in addition to voltage regulation.

Both the regulator and the current limiter were peculiar kind of relays, themselves inexact and prone to diverse failure modes.

In some of the DC generators, the current limiting was done by parallel + series stator winding. Somewhat more stable, but less efficient.

And here comes the end of 1960s. Solid-state rectifiers became available and cheap enough, cars got their alternators (synchronous generator + semiconductor diode rectifier).

Because of the wide variation of the rpm, alternators were designed to work in current-source mode. Open-circuit voltage roughly proportional to rpm, inductive resistance also proportional to rpm. Shorting it does not increase the current much. No external current limiter needed. Brushes got only the exitation current (~20x less) and themselves stopped being a pain of maintenance.

The whole thing became much less of a hassle. That's why people think DC generators are less reliable.

They are inherently just somewhat less reliable. They were great deal less reliable **in cars**.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that both devices had their excitation set to allow them to deliver rated power at rated voltage, a synchronous generator with separately excited field winding and a DC generator with separately excited field winding will both suffer from thermal overload of the armature winding in a sustained fault if the excitation is held constant.  The thermal overload may permanently damage the winding depending on the duration of the overload.  The DC generator may also suffer damage to the commutator and brushes from the elevated armature current.